# What is the relationship between 尉-shaped characters and the pronuncation yu?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm curious about the relationship between 尉-shaped characters and the pronunciation yu. I'm not sure if this is just a Sichuanese thing or not, but here's what I know:

- In some Sichuanese topolects 蔚蓝(色) is read `yu lan`.
- It has been said that Deng Xiaoping often said: 芋问, which is really just: 慰问.
- 告慰 can also be read `gao yu`, in some Sichuanese topolects.
- 蔚 can also be a surname that is read: `Yu`.
- 尉迟 is also a double barreled surname.

The `yu` pronunciation seems like a bit of an anomaly and I'm not really sure how it fits in here. Perhaps it was that the surname was so strong in some areas that it affected the pronunciations of these other words.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two syllables are related.「尉」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*ʔut-s/**) has two Mandarin descendants, which are approximately **yu** and **wei**.

Several OC syllables with initial **/*ʔu-/** basically evolved into Mandarin **w** and Mandarin **yu**; you can see the same phenomenon with the phonetic component「」:

- 溫 **wēn**
- 慍 **yùn**

Answer (score 0):

尉迟 rooted from vichy, same as in victoria

Answer (score 0):

I've often wondered how people decided on the pronunciation of characters.

Apparently, huǒ + shī + cùn + rén or yí can equal yù

Quite how this decision was reached is beyond me!

尉: Main pronunciation 主要发音: wèi Other pronunciations 其它发音: wèi,yù,yùn

示shì (actually a changed form of 火huǒ, I read)
尸shī
寸cùn
rén, yí

: 古文仁。或从尸。按古文夷亦如此。

We know that, in Chinese F may be pronounced H, L may be R, R may be L, N may be L.

Maybe, a double U can become a U?